# SwiftUI's fileImporter showing AXRuntimeCommon or DocumentManager errors

Tags: swift, swiftui

When using .fileImporter, while everything runs correctly, I'm seeing some errors come through- different depending on if I'm running on device or on the simulator. For example, the following View:

```
struct ExtraSimplePDFViewer: View {
    @State private var importText = "NO"
    @State private var showingDirectory = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                showingDirectory.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Load PDF")
            }.fileImporter(isPresented: $showingDirectory, allowedContentTypes: [.pdf], allowsMultipleSelection: false) { result in
                do {
                    guard let url: URL = try result.get().first else { return }
                    if url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                        importText = "YES"
                    }
                    url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            
            Text(importText)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

This, when run on the simulator, will show:

[AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: Sandbox
[DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}

On device, it is slightly different:

[AXRuntimeCommon] AX Lookup problem - errorCode:1100 error:Permission denied portName:'com.apple.iphone.axserver
... (this has more details, and repeats a few times)

Now everything works as expected, and the best I could find searching on this was basically to just ignore the chatter...but most of those replies were a couple of years old. Surely if this is still happening years later there must be a fix...right?

Comment: — Did you ever find a cause/solution to this?  A bit over a year later and I too am experiencing this exact same set of errors.